# Why did I lose money when I won at Pazaak in KOTOR?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

I just won a Pazaak game vs Sol'aa in the Jedi Enclave where I bet 50 credits. After the game the popup said "*Credits lost: 50*" and "*Item gained*". I can't recall him mentioning a prize other than money and I have no clue what I received.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many pazaak players in KotOR will bet an item when you've otherwise 'cleared them out' (read, won a certain number of games against them).

Functionally, this means you lose your bet but gain an item. It doesn't make any sense, but that's just how it works.

Comment: Any way to figure out what I got? I often get "Item received" from quests but I have no clue what I got.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to trace through a walkthrough to figure those out. I'd pull one up from GameFAQs to find the item, but it's blocked at my workplace.